# Debian: Eclipse 3.8.1 doesn't know anything anymore about Java

Tags: linux, debian, java, eclipse

I work on a Debian testing, with an Eclipse installed from the repositories (current version: 3.8.1). Since my latest apt-get upgrade, Eclipse "doesn't understand Java" anymore: no Java perspectives, no proper loading of Java project (i.e. they are not recognized as Java projects), no possibility to create a Java project, no `Java` entry in the preferences...

After fighting for a while, I uninstalled and purged all Eclipse-related packages, removed the `.eclipse` directory in my homedir, checked that I had a proper JDK installed, re-installed the `eclipse` package, started in a brand new workspace... And I got the same behaviour again, as if Eclipse didn't know anything about Java.

What am I missing?

Comment: I haven't checked but from your description i'd guess the jdt is packaged separately. Try "apt-cache search jdt".

Comment: @user2543253 `eclipse-jdt` is a dependency of the `eclipse` package. It is therefore installed on my system.

Comment: And it did actually install the org.eclipse.jdt feature? Any messages in the Eclipse logs about not being able to load a specific plugin?

Comment: Yes, the plugin appears in `usr/share/eclipse/plugins` and in the installation details window within the IDE. The logfile is really short, nothing regarding the failure to load a plugin.

Comment: Did you solve this? I found the time to check in my own Debian testing. Doesn't happen there. My last idea would be to try to start the installed Eclipse inside itself as an "Eclipse Application" and use the OSGi console to diagnose plugin problems. (I think it's also possible to use the OSGi console from the shell but I've never done that)

Comment: @user2543253 Honestly, I don't know how to do that (run Eclipse as an Eclipse app). I guess must open it as a project first?

Comment: If you open "Debug Configurations" from the "Run" menu you will have "Eclipse Application" on  the left. When you select this and click the "New" button and without changing the "Run a product" selection "Debug" this, you will get another instance of your Eclipse but one where you can enter OSGi commands at the console of the first Eclipse (You might have to switch to "OSGi Console" in the Cosole view). Somewhere out there there's a reference of all the OSGi commands and some of them can be used to find out what's wrong with plugins. You can also try "Enable tracing" in the launch config.

Comment: @user2543253 I don't have a "Debug Configurations" item in the "Run" menu. The only item there is the "External tools" submenu (with "Run as", "External tools config" and "organize favorites").

Comment: Do you have the "org.eclipse.debug.core" and "org.eclipse.debug.ui" plugins? They're in the "eclipse-platform-data" package. If not, that might explain, why your java plugin doesn't work. AFAIK it depends on them.

Comment: @user2543253 package is installed, plugins are here :-/

Comment: Hm. No ideas anymore except playing with what you can do on the shell, but I don't have much experience with that. I guess you already tried starting Eclipse with -debug ...

Comment: Are Eclipse and the JDK of the same bitness (32/64) ? Read also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine).

Comment: @harrymc yes, everybody is 64bits (and Eclipse starts, it does find its JRE - it just doesn't even start looking for a JDK).

Comment: I had cases where the JDK was not found automatically, which I fixed by specifying it manually in the project's properties.

Comment: @harrymc In my position I don't even have the possibility to do that, I have no Java-related options in project properties.

Comment: Ensure that  the hidden files `.project` and `.classpath` exist (see [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/68409/)), and see if you can find the java builder in the `.project` file (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6534212/165358)). If nothing rings a bell then try to create a new Java project and if it has Java then either transfer your source files to it and abandon the old one, or use it to compare `.project` and `.classpath` with the old project.

Comment: @harrymc You misunderstand the issue. The problem is independent from the existence or the loading of a project. I do not have the ability to create a Java project.

Comment: That's a real weirdo. (1) Try using [this procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28714424/165358) together with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14114268/165358) to reinstall. (2) Did you install Eclipse from the Linux repository or directly from the Eclipse web site? If so, try the other one. (3) Ensure you install Eclipse IDE for Java Developers or Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

Comment: @harrymc I did all that already, before posting. Current install is from the Debian repository, I'll switch to a manual install from the current version on the Eclipse website after the bounty expires.

Comment: Unless someone comes up with a better idea, my only remaining idea is to uninstall and wipeout Eclipse completely, as discussed in some of the links I gave above, then install the Java version from the Eclipse website.

Comment: This has happened to me and my friends countless times. I wish I could remember what we did to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Eclipse installation has a problem, even when you reinstall completely.

As you are currently using the Eclipse package from the Debian distribution,
I suggest to uninstall and wipe it out completely, then download and
install Eclipse IDE for Java Developers or Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
from the [Eclipse website](https://eclipse.org/).

Answer (score 0):

just **rm -r .eclipse** on your home directory. Maybe it is caused by the wrong configurations of eclipse.

Comment: Already tried, as mentionned in the question. Anyway, I have given up on the issue, I'm not relying anymore on the Eclipse implementation proposed by the Debian repositories.